# Compare Strings in a Switch Statement / Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, switch-statement, compare

i have a Question. The Question is the following:
How can i compare a String in Matlab?

I have a variable, it's called data. This variable represents the current String that i want to compare if there is a Substring in it.

I have a lot of different possibilities, this is the reason why i want to use the Switch-Statement.

In the Code-Example you can see the Switch with the Variable "data". If the Variable includes the Substring 'Start' the following case should be execute. Otherwise the "otherwise" Statement should be used.

I hope you can understand what i wanna do. Thanks for your help and Support.

```
    function testObj = workflow(testObj, data)



            switch data
                case strfind(data, 'Start')>5
                    disp('Yes')

                case strfind(data, 'End')>10
                    disp('Yes')

                case strfind(data, 'NewTest')>15
                    disp('Yes')

                otherwise
                    disp('No')
            end


        end
```

Documentation:

> A switch block conditionally executes one set of statements from several choices. Each choice is a case.
>
> An evaluated switch_expression is a scalar or string. An evaluated
>   case_expression is a scalar, a string, or a cell array of scalars or
>   strings. The switch block tests each case until one of the cases is
>   true. A case is true when:
>
> For numbers, eq(case_expression,switch_expression).
>
> For strings, strcmp(case_expression,switch_expression).
>
> For objects that support the eq function,
>   eq(case_expression,switch_expression).
>
> For a cell array case_expression, at least one of the elements of the
>   cell array matches switch_expression, as defined above for numbers,
>   strings, and objects.
>
> When a case is true, MATLAB executes the corresponding statements, and
>   then exits the switch block.
>
> otherwise is optional, and executes only when no case is true.

Comment: Did you even read the documentation?

Comment: @David Yes i read the Documentation, but there  is no Information about it in.

Comment: why no `if`, `elseif`, ...?

Comment: @m.s. it would be possible to solve the Problem with if,elseif... but i had this question and i think the structure would be much more better than with if elseif

Answer (score 0):

switch works differently, as you wrote it you can choose, in `case` statement, from possible complete values of data, you might want

```
switch strfind( data, 'Start') > 5
    case true
        disp( 'Yes')
    otherwise
        disp( 'No')
end
```

or use `if` for this, shorter.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i search another solution, becouse in the future there will be a lot of different cases... i added some new code to the question to explain it a Little bit more

Answer (score 0):

You explained, that you have many possibilities for the content String you want to search in `data`. If you use `switch data`, you will always compare `data` to some other string using `strcmp`. That will probably not be helpful for fullfilling the programs' task, because `strcmp` compares for **equality**, not for containing.

If you don't want to use `if`, `elseif`, etc., one option would be a loop. Save all the possible strings in a cell array, let's call it `compareStrings`, and iterate through the array.

```
for ii = 1:length(compareStrings)
  if strfind(data,compareStrings{ii})
    disp('Yes')
    disp (compareStrings{ii})
  end
end
```

Comment: Personally I'd do all the `strfind` using `cellfun` first then use a `switch` statement. If you change it accordingly, I'll +1 it. Otherwise, let me know my method isn't right.